# Programs don't show up in Windows 10 search

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, application-launch

If I search for a standard `.exe` program I might use often, it almost never shows up in Windows search. If I'm lucky, it might be able to find a folder and I might get to it from there, but otherwise it seems it must be from the stupid app store if I want to be able to search for it. I never use search for anything other than hoping to launch an `.exe` that for some reason didn't make it into any of the several folders apparently tell what's in the start menu. What's the deal with that, as well? Why are there multiple folders for start menu items? I would laugh at the employee who suggested that during the meeting.

Enclosed is some index settings I set a while ago; I just selected everything I thought would cover my bases at the time.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[Cortana not finding Desktop apps when searching for them](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/cortana-not-finding-desktop-apps-when-searching/f612e995-6664-4b91-b6ae-96790e763858)

> I reinstalled [Cortana] using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Open and elevated CMD window (rightclick --> run as admin)
> 2. Start powershell (type 'powershell' without quotes and press enter)
> 3. Run the command:
>
> Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach
>   {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register
>   "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
>
> Within 10 seconds my search was back to normal and I could finally put
>   this problem to rest.

Comment: You should quote the relevant part on the page.